# Is there a good resource on all different formatting and writing styles throughout history?

Tags: creative-writing, style, formatting, resources

I noticed writers in the past used a different format, in terms of punctuation, indentation, quotations, spacing, and paragraph length, and the format can be different from author to author and from book to book. So I was wondering if there was a sort of resource book that details all the styles people adopted. The reason I want a book like this is that it can really be fun to change your formatting style and writing style.

Comment: I did a light edit on your question (and shortened the title).  I also added the [tag:formatting] tag, since you mention formatting several times.  But I want to be sure I understood you correctly.  Do you mean things like font, placement on a page, use of indentations, and how to do lists?  Is this about printing books?  Thanks.

Comment: more about writing style, like using punctuation, indentations, what type of quote, spacing, paragraph length, etc.

Comment: That helps, thanks.  I am keeping [tag:formatting], because some of what you mention is actual formatting, and adding [tag:style].  Could you please edit the original question to include your clarification?

Comment: This is an interesting question, and it would be really cool if such a book existed, but it seems that it would be prohibitively inclusive and research-intensive. Would you be satisfied with several sources with narrower scopes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't been able to find a book, per se, but I have found a couple of resources that might work for your other request be being able to adopt someone else's writing style. I did a Google search on: "history of" "writing styles"; "history of" "writing styles" book.

Here are some of the results that seem to fit your wishes best.

## A writer’s most prized possession is his or her own unique writing style.

https://www.freelancewriting.com/creative-writing/writing-style/

## Famous Authors and Their Writing Styles

https://www.craftyourcontent.com/famous-authors-writing-styles/

## How have authors' writing styles changed in the last few centuries?

https://www.quora.com/How-have-authors-writing-styles-changed-in-the-last-few-centuries

The Quora page has links to similar questions, so maybe you can find something there.

The only books I could find were about writing materials, history of languages, type of communication (including animal communication), and nothing that remotely came close to describing the how/why Shakespeare is different than J. K. Rowling, let alone how to duplicate the styles.

It seems to me this would be an obvious book to have written, since it's a book about writers for writers, yet I can't find it, nor can the 70+ other people who looked at this question. I'm not a writer, but I do a lot of online research, so I thought I would be able to come up with something better.

I know a couple of writers, so I'll ask them offline and see if they know of anything. If they do, I'll update this answer.

## Edit:

I got some hits from the writers I know.

"Writer's Guide: History", By Henry J. Steffen and Mary Jane Dickerson
[https://www.amazon.com/Writers-Guide-History-Writing-Curriculum/dp/0669120022](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0669120022)

"On Writing", by Stephen King
[https://www.amazon.com/Writing-10th-Anniversary-Memoir-Craft/dp/1439156816](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1439156816)

**Disclaimer**: I haven't read either book, so I don't know if it's what you're looking for. Links provided only for further context, not purchase or retailer suggestions.